# Update a description from file based on player location

Tags: c++, coordinates, fstream

I'm creating a text based adventure in C++ and want to be able to give generic descriptions for certain areas.

For example, the area [600,20],[1600,20],[1600,240],[600,240] might need the description "Wide open pastureland". I've managed to do the area check myself;

```
struct point{
int x;
int y;
};

bool inarea = false;

point TL = {600,20};
point BR = {1600,240};

if(location[0]<=TL.x || location[0]>=BR.x){
    inarea = false;
    cout << "Outside area, fails on X" << endl;
return;
}
if(location[1]<=TL.y || location[1]>=BR.y){
    inarea = false;
    cout << "Outside area, fails on Y" << endl;
return;
}
inarea = true;
cout << "In area" << endl;
return;
```

But I don't know how I can load the areas from a file given a specific format, eg:

*600,20 1600,240 Wide open pasturelands*

I've searched the web and believe I need to look at fstream but haven't managed to find anything that explains it quite simply/line by line.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The key word you seem to be missing is "parser" or "parsing". Feed our good friend Google with "c++ parsing a text file" and you will find what you need, including numerous answers here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @kuroineko That seems to be the problem! I knew it'd be something simple I didn't know. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can use smth like this to parse

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *in = "600,20 1600,240 Wide open pasturelands";
    int a, b, c, d;
    char discription[100];
    sscanf(in, "%d,%d %d,%d %[^\n]s", &a, &b, &c, &d, discription);
    printf(" a = %d\n b = %d\n c = %d\n d = %d\n disc = %s\n",a,b,c,d, discription);
}
```